# Time Range restriction on OWL

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

We have a class `CBSTV`, which has some subclasses like `News`, `Documentary`, and etc. The data property `time` will specify the time of each program. For example, the `news` is every day between 16:00:00-17:00:00. I tried to represent this restriction this way:

`dateTime [>= T16:00:00Z, <=T17:00:00Z ]`

but, it is wrong, anyone know the correct way to represent this

also, we have another data property `duration`. For instance the duration of the `news` is between 45 minutes to one hour. I don't know how I should represent this one too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype for recurring times (e.g., 17:00 every day) is not xsd:dateTime but xsd:time

Comment: I know but there is no time datatype in Protege, I am curious how I can do it Protege

Comment: The main problem there is that xsd:time is not among the datatypes that OWL 2 must support; this means that tools are not required to understand it. Typing `xsd:time` should still be parsed correctly, but YMMV.

Comment: Why they did not implement `xsd:time` do they have a reason for it?

Comment: I can't find any documentation for it

Comment: @Ignazio I added paper and the relevant part to your answer.